# Why doesn't Visual Studio launch all of a sudden?

Tags: visual-studio

My problem is that I was coding a lot in VS, but I haven't used it for a month and I need to use it again but whenever I try to open the application after install, it displays an error message once then if I try to open it, it constantly gives a second error message (linked pictures below). Now I tried to search for a fix but no one seems to have this exact issue. I tried reinstalling VS 2019 but it did not help, I installed VS 2022 Preview but it has the same error. I tried deleting the "ComponentModelCache" folder and starting with admin rights, but that also didn't work. I even tested it on a new user account but the issue occurred there as well. I wonder if anyone has met this issue. Help would be greatly appreciated because I don't want to change to a different IDE.

[error I get once after reinstalling VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACjCV.png)

[error I get constantly when opening VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzfsD.png)

Comment: You will want to run the appropriate DISM and SFC commands to repair the system corruption that more than likely exists on your system.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019